# Container iterator operating on component's attribute

Tags: c++

Having following class

```
class Foo {
   int element1;
   bool element2;
   Bar *ptr_element;
}
```

I've put it in `vector` and I'd like to iterate over it using iterator.

```
std::vector<Foo*> fooVec;
//...
```

What I'd need to do to have iterator return directly `Bar *ptr_elemnt` attribute of an instance instead of instance of `Foo`?

Assume I'd like to do something like that:

```
[some type, probably Bar*]::iterator iter;
for (iter = fooVec.begin(); iter != fooVec.end(); iter++) {
   iter->barFunction();
   // instead of iter->ptr_element->barFunction();
}
```

Where `barFuntion()` is some public function in Bar class.

So far best idea for the solution has been creating completely new container and create iterator for it. But **my requirement is to keep vector container**.
Is it for example possible to create iterator specified not for container (`vector`), but for contained class (`Foo`)? Or what option would you suggest here?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to all of you for pointing out I forgot to add `public` in my code. It should be like this (leaving old version intact for future reference):

```
class Foo {
public:
   int element1;
   bool element2;
   Bar *ptr_element;
}
```

Comment: the `Bar` attribute is private, there is no way to access it directly

Comment: What's wrong with `for (auto foo : fooVec) { foo->ptr_element->barFunction(); }`? Assuming, of course, that it's not `private` (or there are other accessors to it).

Comment: @Fureeish no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to make a `std::vector<Foo*>::iterator` return anything other than a `Foo*` when dereferenced.  However, you can wrap the `iterator` inside another type that exposes what you need, eg:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    int element1;
    bool element2;
    Bar *ptr_element;
};

struct FooAdapter
{
    using iterator = std::vector<Foo*>::iterator;
    iterator m_iter;

    FooAdapter() = default;
    FooAdapter(iterator iter) : m_iter(iter) {}

    Bar*& operator*() { return (*m_iter)->ptr_element; }
    Bar* operator->() { return (*m_iter)->ptr_element; }

    bool operator==(iterator rhs) const { return m_iter == rhs; }
    bool operator!=(iterator rhs) const { return m_iter != rhs; }

    FooAdapter& operator++() { ++m_iter; return *this; }
    FooAdapter operator++(int) { return FooAdapter(m_iter++); }

    // other operators as needed...
};

FooAdapter iter;
for (iter = fooVec.begin(); iter != fooVec.end(); ++iter) {
   iter->barFunction();
   // instead of iter->ptr_element->barFunction();
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/BcveQy)

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, it's not possible to use `ptr_element`, because it is `private` in `Foo`, and you did not show us any way of accessing it. This answer replaces `class Foo` with `struct Foo` in order to provide access to `ptr_element`.

---

There are two ways to call `barFunction()` on every element that I'd recommend:

#### Plain, old, range-based `for` loop (C++11):

```
for (auto foo_ptr : fooVec) {
    foo_ptr->ptr_element->barFunction();
}
```

#### `for_each` with projection (C++20):

```
std::ranges::for_each(
        fooVec,
        [](auto ptr) {
            ptr->barFunction();
        },
        &Foo::ptr_element
);
```

With the second one being the closest to what you want - the lambda's argument (`ptr`) is a result of a *projection* done by taking every `Foo*` and extracting `ptr_element` from each of them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your members are inaccessible because they are `private`(default permissions for classes). Depends on requirements you can make them public:

```
class Foo {
public:
    int element1;
    bool element2;
    Bar *ptr_element;
};
```

Or turn `Foo` into, `struct`(default permissions are public):

```
struct Foo {
    int element1;
    bool element2;
    Bar *ptr_element;
};
```

After that, you will be able to access `Foo`'s members through `->` operator:

```
std::vector<Foo> foos(10);
for(auto it = foos.begin(); it != foos.end(); ++it)
{
    it->element1 = -1;
}
```

Or alternative syntax:

```
for(Foo& foo : foos)
{
    foo.element1 = -1;
}
```